# Tomcat 7 Websockects through AJP not working. Any suggestions?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, ajp, atmosphere

Does anyone know if the Tomcat release 7.0.27 AJP Connecter can support http upgrade (websockets) if setting your protocol to the AjpNioProtocol. 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html#Connector_Comparison

I'm working with atmosphere, but even with a basic socket request, the client websocket closes. Atmo Error: Connection closed with no close frame being sent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AJP protocol does not support WebSocket. If you use HTTP rather than AJP with your reverse proxy it might work (depends on the proxy).

Comment: Utter nonsense. As of Jan 2015, there is no support in any AJP implementation (including NIO) for WebSocket.