# Is is mandatory to use httpd with tomcat?

Tags: apache, apache2, tomcat6

Is is mandatory to use tomcat with httpd? Cant we just use tomcat directly avoid one more layer? We are running tomcat on port 80 and not using apache web server. Is this OK? Why typically httpd is used with tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link "[Why use Apache Web server in front of Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122345/why-use-apache-web-server-in-front-of-glassfish-or-tomcat)" (it seems) explains your question very well.

In case I have misinterpreted the problem statement, let me know.