# glassfish v3: package static resource files in a war file, a good idea?

Tags: glassfish

The issue with that approach is that every request to any static resource will have to go through the servlet container.   From performance point of view, is it a good idea? How would you recommend to server static resources from a glassfish v3 server? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question covers the issue better than I am able to: [Why use Apache Web Server in front of Glassfish or Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122345/why-to-use-apache-web-server-in-front-of-glassfish)

Comment: thanks. but I am not looking to using apache at this moment. Just trying to make most of glassfish servers for now.

Comment: To sum up the link, and the links it leads to: if your website traffic is high enough, you should move up to apache for static content, but for a smaller website, Glassfish will be just fine.  You might want to consider turning on (and tuning for your site) http file caching.  I still think you should read the question I linked you to, as well as this link in particular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654701/how-much-slower-is-serving-static-content-from-tomcat